# zip archives created inside mpi4py cannot be opened

Tags: python, linux, zip, mpi, mpi4py

I ran some code in python that created a large number of .csv files. I'm doing this on a supercomputer and I used [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to manage the parallel processing. Several processes ran on each node, with a number of operations done by each process. Each process created a .csv file. I didn't want to drop all the .csv files onto the main hard disk because there were so many. So instead, I wrote them to local SSDs, each SSD connected to a node. Then, I wanted to zip all the .csvs from each SSD into one zip archive per node and put the archive on the main hard drive. I did it like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import os
import platform
import zipfile

# MPI setup
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

def get_localrank(comm):
    comm_localrank = MPI.Comm.Split_type(comm, MPI.COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0)
    return comm_localrank.Get_rank()

def ls_csv(path, ext=".csv"):
    all_files = os.listdir(path)
    return [ path+"/"+f for f in all_files if f.endswith(ext) ]

def ssd_to_drive(comm, drive_path):
    # only execute on one MPI process per node
    if get_localrank(comm) == 0:

        # every node's file needs a different name
        archive_name = drive_path + "/data_" + platform.node() + ".zip"

        csvs = ls_csv("ssd_path")

        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for csvf in csvs:
            zf.write(csvf)

        zf.close()

##copy archived csvs from the ssds back to project
ssd_to_drive(comm=comm, drive_path="mypath")
```

I get the zip files back in the directory I want them, but I can't open them. Either they are corrupt or unzip thinks they are part of a multi-part archive, and if that's the case, I don't see how to reconstruct them.

When I do `less data_nodename.zip`, I get the following (where the alphanumeric string before each error statement represents "nodename"):

```
e33n08
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

f09n09
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

f09n10
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

e33n06
Zipfile is disk 37605 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
     which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 25182).

f09n11
Zipfile is disk 40457 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
     which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 740).

a06n10
end-of-central-directory record claims this
  is disk 11604 but that the central directory starts on disk 48929; this is a
  contradiction.  Attempting to process anyway.

f10n14
end-of-central-directory record claims this
  is disk 15085 but that the central directory starts on disk 52010; this is a
  contradiction.
```

Of note, I only have 3 zip files that seem to claim to be the beginning of the multi-disk archive (e33n08, f09n09, f09n10), but at least 4 references to a "beginning of central directory" disk (25182, 740, 48929, 52010).

So now I can't figure out if these are corrupt or if `zipfile` really thought it was creating a multi-disk archive, why this happened, or how to reconstruct the archive if it really is multi-disk.

Finally, when I did this procedure with multiple mpi tasks but only one node, the single zip archive created was fine and readable with `less` and `unzip`.

Comment: you should first try this on a login node, and then with `mpi4py` but only one MPI task. Note your zip archives will be corrupted if you run more that one MPI task per node. what does `file ...zip` returns? does your `unzip` version matches the requirements?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to add that when I used only one node, the zip output was fine. Editing to add

Comment: The output of ```file``` is ```Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract```. Also I have ```$ unzip -h```
```UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP``` and ```$ unzip -v | grep -i zip64``` 
        ```ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)```

Comment: creating of the zip is restricted to one mpi task per node by the ```if get_localrank(comm) == 0``` line

Comment: when running on one node, do you use `mpirun` and `mpi4py` ?

Comment: yes its exactly the same, just fewer processes (few enough that only 1 node is required). I use mpi4py as above, and I call the script with jsrun (i.e jsrun -n 42 python3 myscript.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I missed this, but the files were indeed corrupt. The job had exited before writing the zip archives was complete.